# MongoDB C Driver: How to replace a document

Tags: c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver

How can we replace a document in MongoDB using Mongo C Driver?

Are there any APIs available?. In Mongo shell I can use replaceOne for this purpose.

But how can I do this through my C program?

Answer (score 1):

There is a full list of drivers available for MongoDB at https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/ and the driver for C is located at http://mongoc.org/.

There is a selection of basic CRUD operations at
http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/tutorial.html#tutorial-crud-operations. Have a look through the API for the method in question.